# Chrome Browser and CORS issue when caching present in request headers

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, cors, cache-control

I am not sure if this problem has been discussed here, but something is strange. I am running this version of Chrome in Windows 10:
Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have a domain, say p.com,
it is fetching a PDF file from the Google Cloud Storage, with url such as this:
https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/aaa.pdf

The Google Cloud Storage already has CORS setup as such:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Date", "Range", "Vary", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]}]
```

When I do a fetch without caching in the request headers, it is successful. But when I enable caching in the request headers such as this:

```
fetch("https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/aaa.pdf", {
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "max-age=315360000",
    "expires": "Mon, 06 Dec 2021 06:39:19 GMT",
    "pragma": "cache"
  },

  "method": "GET",
});
```

It fails with this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/aaa.pdf' from origin 'http://p.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

My question is, is CORS and caching a binary choice? Either or? I mean you cannot have both. I would like to enable CDN and caching so that the resource is loaded quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CORS configuration must explicitly state what request headers are allowed (other than a small number of headers already considered "safe"). So you're getting that error because you added request headers that aren't allowed. To fix that you need to [include](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#cors-elements) all allowed headers in the `responseHeader` field.

That said, are you sure you actually want to use those headers? While it's possible to use `Cache-Control` as a request header, it's unusual and doesn't "enable caching". More likely you want those headers to be set in the *response*, which you can do by [configuring](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control) Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Yes, I was triggering a request for caching, but thanks for the pointer to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with this quite a bit myself, I also observed that cached requests do not contain the `Origin` header in Chrome, so I had to disable caching to avoid CORS issues. I did this by adding `cache: 'no-store'` to my request config:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-store', // for some reason Chrome's caching doesn't send Origin
})
```

FWIW, Safari did not exhibit this behavior in my tests.